# Merging the same labels for counting

Tags: python, pandas, merge, count

I have a huge dataframe as:

```
  country1  import1  export1 country2  import2  export2
0      USA       12       82  Germany       12       82
1  Germany       65       31   France       65       31
2  England       74       47    Japan       74       47
3    Japan       23       55  England       23       55
4   France       48       12      Usa       48       12
```

`export1` and `import1` belongs to `country1`
`export2` and `import2` belongs to `country2`

I want to count export and import values by country.

Output may be like:

```
 country | total_export | total_import
______________________________________________
USA      |  12211221    | 212121
France   |    4545      | 5454
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) first:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(data.reset_index(), ['country','import','export'], i='index', j='tmp')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   country  import  export
0      USA      12      82
1  Germany      65      31
2  England      74      47
3    Japan      23      55
4   France      48      12
5  Germany      12      82
6   France      65      31
7    Japan      74      47
8  England      23      55
9      Usa      48      12
```

And then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('country', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   country  import  export
0  England      97     102
1   France     113      43
2  Germany      77     113
3    Japan      97     102
4      USA      12      82
5      Usa      48      12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the table into two parts and concatenate them:

```
func = lambda x: x[:-1] # or lambda x: x.rstrip('0123456789')
​
data.iloc[:,:3].rename(func, axis=1).\
append(data.iloc[:,3:].rename(func, axis=1)).\
groupby('country').sum()
```

​
Output:

```
         import  export
country                
England      97     102
France      113      43
Germany      77     113
Japan        97     102
USA          12      82
Usa          48      12
```

Comment: @jezrael `lambda x: x.rstrip('0123456789')`

Comment: yop, understand